# python If I have a dictonary with keys that contain mutliple values and a single value how to filter out only keys that contain multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

`word_freq = {'is': [1, 3, 4, 8, 10],'no' :[1], 'yes':[1,2]}`

I want to only get 'is' and 'yes' using the fact that they contain more than one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filtered_keys = [k for k in word_freq.keys() if len(word_freq[k])>1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for i in word_freq:
    if len(word_freq[i]) > 1:
        print(word_freq[i])
```

It loops through the dictionary in `word_freq` and if the `items/values` in the `word_freq` are more than 1 then it prints them out.